# Migrating from java8 to java 17 with spring boot 3 causing ESAPI issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, esapi

I have migrated from java 8 to java 17 and spring boot to 3.0.4. I have jwt security protection in my code that uses jwtRequestFilter class as shown below

```
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
```

which overrides the following method

```
 @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
```

in this method im using  esapi httpUtilities to add a header as below

```
 ESAPI.httpUtilities().addHeader(HttpServletResponse response, String name, String value);
```

but its throwing the following compilation error

```
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI
```

since with spring boot 3.x javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; is not supported im using jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; but  ESAPI internally using javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; so im getting that exception.

Please let mw know if Is there any other way that I can configure to make my code work?

Answer (score 2):

They are not planning to move to Jakarta packages, but there is a workaround if you want to get it to work with Spring 6.

[Quote](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/README.md):

> #### Special note regarding Spring Boot 3, Spring 6, Tomcat 10 and other applications / libraries requiring Jakarta EE
>
> **IMPORTANT:** We are aware that all versions of ESAPI (unless you are using very select parts) do not work with Jakarta EE. Jakarta EE relies on **jakarta.servlet-api**. ESAPI is built to use **javax.servlet-api**. This causes things like Spring Boot 3, Spring 6, Tomcat 10, the latest version of Jetty, etc. to fail to load certain (well, many) ESAPI classes. The reason for this is that the package names between these 2 libraryes are different! The dependency **javax.servlet-api** has a package namespace of `javax.servlet`. The **jakarta.servlet-api** library is using the package namespace of `jakarta.servlet`. So references to things like `ServletRequest`, `ServletResponse`, etc. in ESAPI are using `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` and `javax.servlet.ServletResponse` respectively. We cannot make it work for both at once and we will not stop supporting **javax.servlet-api**, which is what most of our existing ESAPI clients are using.
>
> Therefore **PLEASE STOP** sending us emails and/or creating GitHub issues regarding this! Instead, please read ongoing the GitHub discussion [#768](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/768) for further details.

https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/768

Comment: Can you please help me to know what workaround should I need to do to make it work with spring boot 3. also, is there any alternative available that I can use instead of ESAPI?  Thank you @zawarudo

Comment: It is explained in the link that I provided
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/768

Comment: There is an alternative to the ESAPI Encoder, namely the OWASP Java Encoder project, but not, as far as I know, for ESAPI's HTTPUtilities. In the referenced GitHub discussions link, Jeff Williams (aka, planetlevel) mentions trying the Maven Shade plugin. I would suggest giving that approach a try.